# Cluster reconciliation in the event of node loss

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-health-check

I have a cluster of 3 nodes that I'd like to recover fast after a single node loss. By recovering I mean that I resume communication with my service after a reasonable amount of time (preferably configurable).

Following are various details:

k8s version:

```
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"5", GitVersion:"v1.5.7", GitCommit:"8eb75a5810cba92ccad845ca360cf924f2385881", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2017-04-27T10:00:30Z", GoVersion:"go1.7.5", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"5", GitVersion:"v1.5.7", GitCommit:"8eb75a5810cba92ccad845ca360cf924f2385881", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2017-04-27T09:42:05Z", GoVersion:"go1.7.5", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

I have a service distributed over all 3 nodes. With one node failing I observe the following behavior:

1. api server fails over to another node and kubernetes service endpoint shows the correct IP address (custom fail-over).
2. api server is not responding on `10.100.0.1` (its cluster IP)
3. after some time, all relevant service endpoints are cleared (e.g. in `kubectl get ep --namespace=kube-system` shows no ready addresses for all endpoints)
4. the service in question is not available on the service IP (due to the above)

The service has both readiness/liveness probes and only a single instance is `ready` at any given time with all being `live`. I've checked that the instance that is supposed to be available is also available - i.e. both `ready`/`live`.

This continues for more than 15min before the service Pod that was running on the lost node receives a `NodeLost` status, at which point the endpoints are re-populated, and I can access the service as usual.

I have tried fiddling with `pod-eviction-timeout`, `node-monitor-grace-period` settings to no avail - the time is always roughly the same.

Hence, my questions:

1. Where can I read up on the behavior of the key k8s components in case of a node loss in detail?
2. What would be the combination of parameters to reduce the time it takes the cluster to reconcile since this is supposed to be used in a test?

Comment: Can you clarify a few things.  Are your master components (kube-apiserver, kube-controller-manager) on all 3 nodes?  What instructions did you use to setup replicated apiserver and controller manager?  Where is etcd?  On all 3 nodes too?  Which service are you talking about not responding?  IIRC, the kube-apiserver is not behind a Kubernetes service in an HA configuration, but behind some other kind of load balancer.  I'm not sure what 10.100.0.1 means in your setup.

Comment: Yes, these services are on all 3 nodes but only a single node is running the api server subset (apiserver/controller-manager/scheduler) at a time.
The replication is custom and uses etcd-backed leader election to choose which node runs the apiserver.
Etcd is also distributed over these 3 nodes.

The non-responding service is a user service but the point is that all endpoints are considered not ready and I guess, hence, the service itself is not available (e.g. no Pod can be reached using the service IP).
Yes, sorry. 10.100.0.1 is the kubernetes service cluster IP (from 10.100.0.0/16)